# Jquery dropdown change event not working

Tags: jquery

I have select tag like below with ID DA*, want to check if the drop down is changing.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function refreshData() {
    console.log('refresh data...');
  }
  
  $('select[id*="DA"]').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      alert('change');
      refreshData();
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropdown " data-val="true" data-val-ddladdnew="Please select a valid DA." data-val-number="The field DA must be a number." data-val-required="The DA field is required." data-value="123456" id="DA_dff57gdc-3421-4b66-9f05-061e7a8l3207__ID"
  name="DA[dff57gdc-3421-4b66-9f05-061e7a8l3207].ID" dropdownaddnew="true" dropdownargument="" dropdownsource="***.Data.Entities.DA" dropdownversion="636245716304981172">
  <option value=''></option>
</select>

<select class="dropdown " data-val="true" data-val-ddladdnew="Please select a valid DA." data-val-number="The field DA must be a number." data-val-required="The DA field is required." data-value="789012" id="DA_a50bfa29-2495-47e4-a52f-fa6a8d1305b0__ID"
  name="DA[a50bfa29-2495-47e4-a52f-fa6a8d1305b0].ID" dropdownaddnew="true" dropdownargument="" dropdownsource="***.Data.Entities.DA" dropdownversion="636245716304981172">
  <option value=''></option>
</select>
```

But on changing the dropdown the refreshData() function is not getting triggered, could anyone let me know what is wrong or is there any other way ?

There is a function initDropdownControls() - which takes the version and entity name and populates the option. The previous code was from right click and view source page, now did inspect and took the code.

```
  <select class="dropdown  select2-offscreen init" data-val="true" data-val-ddladdnew="Please select a valid DA." data-val-number="The field DA must be a number." data-val-required="The DA field is required." data-value="728583" id="DA_cff57bdc-3f21-4b66-9f45-061e7a8a3207__ID" name="DA[cff57bdc-3f21-4b66-9f45-061e7a8a3207].ID" dropdownaddnew="true" dropdownaddnewhandler="***.Areas.Admin.Controllers.DAController+DropDownAddNewHandler" dropdownargument="" dropdownsource="****.Data.Entities.DA" dropdownversion="636245716304981172" tabindex="-1"><option value=""></option><option value="735770">Gibson Test, Ben</option><option value="728583" selected="selected">MuTest, Mathew</option><option value="728429">Murdock, Test</option><option value="728412">Testlast, Test </option><option value="728410">Woll, Test</option><option value="-1">( Add New )</option></select>
```

Which has options, and hope window.onload is the last one which gets triggered after all document.ready. So used that, yes @Rory your snippet is working but hope my problem is something else and am facing the issues still. And I couldn't use .dropdown because the page has many select with that class, and I want on change for only this particular select having DA* in it.

Comment: @Satpal Look at Rory's avatar. Can't you see his eyeballs are gone? ;)

Comment: And how can a change event be triggered when there's nothing to be changed? You'd need more than one option element for that.

Comment: To be of some help, your code works when you actually have more than one `option` element so you can raise a `change` event: https://jsfiddle.net/a1kqh4y0/. If you're still having issues, please give us a working example of the problem. You also don't need `each()` or the `[id]` attribute selector as you can use the `.dropdown` class instead

Comment: There's really no need to use `each()`: `$('select[id*="DA"]').change()` is enough.

Comment: Why do you have `$(this).change()` inside the `$(select).each`? You could just do the change on the select itself.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan updated the question

Comment: Does the `initDropdownControls()` function remove and re-create the `select` elements? If so that's the issue and you'll need to use a delegated event handler instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yes select elements are re-created.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan -    $(parent).append($('<option>', {
                            value: row.ID,
                            text: row.Text,
                            selected: isSelected                            
                        }));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @RoryMcCrossan comments, delegated event handler makes it work as the select element was re-created !

```
$('body').on('change', '.dropdown', function () {
    alert('change');        
    refreshData();        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the other comments have mentioned you don't need to use .each since the alert will already display for a change in each select field given that you have asked it to select all elements with ID starting with "DA". You also didn't had any new values in your options for the function to detect a change.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8pxq6km/)

```
<select class="dropdown " data-val="true" data-val-ddladdnew="Please select a valid DA." data-val-number="The field DA must be a number." data-val-required="The DA field is required." data-value="123456" id="DA_dff57gdc-3421-4b66-9f05-061e7a8l3207__ID" name="DA[dff57gdc-3421-4b66-9f05-061e7a8l3207].ID" dropdownaddnew="true" dropdownargument="" dropdownsource="***.Data.Entities.DA" dropdownversion="636245716304981172">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    </select>


<select class="dropdown " data-val="true" data-val-ddladdnew="Please select a valid DA." data-val-number="The field DA must be a number." data-val-required="The DA field is required." data-value="789012" id="DA_a50bfa29-2495-47e4-a52f-fa6a8d1305b0__ID" name="DA[a50bfa29-2495-47e4-a52f-fa6a8d1305b0].ID" dropdownaddnew="true" dropdownargument="" dropdownsource="***.Data.Entities.DA" dropdownversion="636245716304981172">
    <option value='a'>a</option>
    <option value='b'>b</option>
    <option value='c'>c</option>
</select>
<script>
$('select[id*="DA"').change(function(){
    alert('changed!')
});
</script>
```